# MySQL Query Subtraction values

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have this query:

```
SELECT (
        SELECT purchase_code 
        FROM qa_suppliers_invoices a 
        WHERE a.supplier_invoice_code = b.item_invoicecodesupplier
       ) AS purchase_code, 
      item_code, 
      status_code, 
      itempurchase_quantity, 
      item_costprice 
FROM qa_items_purchases b
ORDER BY purchase_code LIMIT 0,20000;
```

It return the following data
[image]

I want to GROUP like a Purple color line using (item_code) row, i want to add all the (itempurchase_quantity)  making reference to (status_code) row then apply this ecuation (status_15 - status_16) also like the image.

I want this result, GROUP():

```
purchase_code  item_code  status_code  itempurchase_quantity  item_costprice
1              1506       15           713                    126.94
2              1503       16           12                     0.00
2              1683       15           9                      25.28
2              1931       15           60                     0.00
```

In the case of item_code(1997) not exist status_code = 15 There is thus return a negative number(-9) then you do not need to show.

```
2              2325       16           50                     849.97
```

**NOTE:**
I need to disappear all 16 status_code

[`Demo data to play with query at sqlfiddle`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fda66/1)

**UPDATE:**
This is a picture detailing what I need:
[image]

Comment: what you have tried so far? show us some code...

Comment: Only i tryed using, GROUP BY (item_code), but i no have idea how i can add or subtract making reference to status_code row

Comment: ok. one questions, do you have status code as 15 & 16 only?

Comment: ok, let me try. Try @Elvieejo answer and let me know if this is working or not...

Comment: @JohnNuñez when I have more than one status_code for an item_code, how can I decide which status_code for the result?

Comment: @JohnNuñez what do you mean with dissapear all 16 status_code? in your results you're showing one 16 status_code..

Comment: @ElVieejo I want to dissapear 16 status_codes subtracting the 15 codes, Because: 15 = Positive | 16 = Negative

Comment: again, in your results you're showing 16 status_codes.. where are you dissapearing them?

Comment: @ElVieejo, wait i will make another image illustrating what i want

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14211/discussion-between-john-nunez-and-elvieejo)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT 
      a.purchase_code,
      b.item_code, 
      '15' AS status_code,
      SUM(
        CASE b.status_code 
            WHEN 15 THEN b.itempurchase_quantity
        ELSE 
            - (b.itempurchase_quantity) 
        END) 
        AS itempurchase_quantity,
      b.item_costprice
FROM qa_items_purchases b
    INNER JOIN qa_suppliers_invoices a 
        ON a.supplier_invoice_code = b.item_invoicecodesupplier
GROUP BY purchase_code, b.item_code, b.item_costprice
    HAVING itempurchase_quantity > 0
    ORDER BY purchase_code 
    LIMIT 0,20000
```

Comment: It's pseudo-code, not magically copypaste and work.. let me check it anyway

Comment: @JohnNuñez check it now.Missing "Then"

Comment: With you query i get (status_code) are ambiguous error, I'm trying to change some parameters.

Comment: probably because you got to set from which table is every column. I don't got that info , use alias and complete that

Comment: @JohnNuñez have you ckeck my answer? if you add the alias("a" and "b") to each columns, considering from which table they belong, this should work

Comment: @ElVieejo : if you add item_costprice in GROUP BY OP didnt get what he want. see [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b5b86/2)

Answer (score 2):

Use this

```
SELECT purchase_code, item_code, status_code, 
     SUM(case status_code 
         when 15 then itempurchase_quantity
         ELSE (-1*itempurchase_quantity) END
        ) AS itempurchase_quantity
FROM myTable
GROUP BY purchase_code;
```

### [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/52205/1)

**NOTE**

Instead of myTable, you will need to use your data. I have create `myTable` with data that you have shown in image.

I think new query would be

```
SELECT (
    SELECT purchase_code 
    FROM qa_suppliers_invoices a 
    WHERE a.supplier_invoice_code = b.item_invoicecodesupplier
   ) AS purchase_code, 
  item_code, 
  status_code, 
  SUM(case status_code 
         when 15 then itempurchase_quantity
         ELSE (-1*itempurchase_quantity) END
        ) AS itempurchase_quantity, 
  item_costprice 
FROM qa_items_purchases b
GROUP BY purchase_code
ORDER BY purchase_code 
LIMIT 0,20000;
```

---

### Update 1

```
SELECT purchase_code, item_code, status_code, 
       SUM(case status_code 
           when 15 then itempurchase_quantity
           ELSE (-1*itempurchase_quantity) END
          ) AS itempurchase_quantity
FROM myTable
GROUP BY purchase_code, item_code;
```

### [New Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6b168/1)

Comment: I think this will not work, because Item_code and status_code there are not in the group by clause and you are showing this fields in the select, withouy aplying them an aggregate function

Comment: I appreciate your help, just let me attach

Comment: @FahimParkar, Remember that we only need to group the repeated codes (item_code), please look the purchase_code = 2

Comment: only works because item_code is the same on the purchase_code.. But if he wants to use another purchase_code, with differents item_code (you can see like that in the img that he posted), it won't work.That's why  I think that grouping by every  field is more safer

Comment: @JohnNuñez : can you provide expected output for code 2?? Please update your question with expected output for code 2...

Comment: @FahimParkar, again i updated my question, explaining. Thanks

Comment: @JohnNuñez : check my updated answer.. first see the link in **Update 1** and let me know if it is working. if it is what you want, I will updated query in answer too...

Comment: @FahimParkar Please join into the Discution chat. http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14211/discussion-between-john-nunez-and-elvieejo